# Errors when linking 32/64bit assembly in Linux

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, linker-errors, ld

I am new to assembly language programming. I am trying to follow the steps outlined [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) to get a better understanding of assembly and optimization. My operating system is Linux Mint, and I am trying to use the NASM assembler, albeit unsuccessfully.

As in the walkthrough, the code is:

```
BITS 32
GLOBAL main
SECTION .text
main:
    mov eax, 42
    ret
```

It compiles successfully with nasm using the command: `nasm -f elf tiny.asm`

But if I try to use gcc to link with the command: `gcc -Wall -s tiny.o`

I get the following error: 
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `tiny.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

A quick search told me that I should link using this ld command: ld -m elf_i386 -s -o tiny tiny.o

However, doing this gives me the following warning: 
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048060

And if I `./tiny` I get a Segmentation Fault. And `./tiny ; echo $?` also returns the number '139' which is... unexpected.

Browsing around, I see that the problem is solved for some by passing 1 to the eax register and 0 to ebx, and using an int command I'm unfamiliar with to end the program... But considering my objective is to make the program as small as possible, I would rather not add additional lines of code.

I should add that compiling and linking this similar code (GAS):

```
.global main
.text
main:
    mov $32, %eax
```

Using the gcc compiler seems to run flawlessly. I'm at a loss here. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are on 64-bit Linux Mint and trying to create 32-bit application (linking using GCC) try doing `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib` Then try `nasm -f elf32 tiny.asm` and `gcc -m32 -Wall -s tiny.o -o tiny`

Comment: Thank you so much! this solves everything for me, do you mind explaining a little more what the additional options do? Are they simply enabling the 32bit code to function in a 64bit environment?

Comment: By default files needed for _GCC_ to create 32-bit program are not installed on 64-bit Linux. `sudo apt get...` line simply downloads and installs the _GCC_ files needed for 32-bit GCC development on 64-bit Linux Mint. Since you had `BITS 32` at the top of assembler you want to compile that to a 32-bit ELF object which is what `nasm -f elf32 tiny.asm` does )(it output by default a file called `tiny.o`. Object files need to be linked to an executable  `gcc -m32 -Wall -s tiny.o -o tiny` does that. The `-m32` option that I added says we want to generate a 32-bit executable from 32-bit objects.

Comment: By using _GCC_ to link the executable, the generated program actually does some C runtime initialization and then calls the label called `main` as if it was a _C_ function. When you do the `ret` in your `main` it returns back to the C runtime code and exits the program cleanly for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This applies to Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Xubuntu and other modern Ubuntu based distributions. For other Debian systems the information is the same, but you can remove the `sudo` command from the installation command and run the command as the `root` user.

---

By default files needed for *GCC* to create 32-bit program are not installed on 64-bit Linux Mint. This command will install the required files:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

---

To assemble asa 32-bit object, and then link to a 32-bit executable you can do this:

```
nasm -f elf32 tiny.asm -o tiny.o
gcc -m32 -Wall -s tiny.o -o tiny
```

Since you had `BITS 32` at the top of the assembler file you want to compile that to a 32-bit ELF object which is what the `-f elf32` option on the *NASM* command line does.

*GCC* is used to link objects to a final executable. The addition of `-m32` tells *GCC* to link the objects to a 32-bit executable. The `-m32` option overrides the normal default behavior of generating 64-bit executables on a 64-bit Linux distribution.

---

By using GCC to link the executable, the generated program actually supplies a `_start` that does *C* runtime initialization and then calls the label called `main` as if it was a *C* function.

When you do the `ret` in your `main` function it returns back to the *C* runtime code and exits the program cleanly for you.

Using *GCC* is the easier and safer method for new assembly language developers. It also allows you to add code that calls the *C* runtime functions like `printf`, `scanf`, `atoi` and most of the other standard *C* library functions.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, it all makes a lot more sense now. I was unsure of the role the C libraries played. One last question: Without the main function, would I still have access to C's libraries using gcc?

Comment: It is possible to bypass the _C_ runtime using the method in Pikrass's answer and still call the _C_ runtime functions, but it is possible for those functions to act improperly if the runtime isn't set up properly. This can be a big problem if you build with the `-static` option of _GCC_. It is generally safer to do it the way I suggest in this answer. Pikrass's answer is the unsafe method, but it can be done, but you could run the risk of the _C_ runtime functions failing in future releases if not properly initialized.

Comment: If you don't need the _C_ runtime at all you can use Pikrass's answer, although he didn't provide the commands you'd need to compile and link properly.

Comment: That [tutorial](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) you are using as an example actually goes into some detail about bypassing the _C_ runtime startup files later on in the document. I wouldn't consider it if you are new to assembly development.

Answer (score 0):

The default entry point for a program is the `_start` symbol. When you compile with gcc, the compiler creates a function called `_start` doing some setup before calling your `main`. It's actually part of the C library I believe. Because you're using a more low-level tool, you're not linking to the C library and hence you have to do this yourself.

So just change your `main` to `_start` and ld won't complain anymore. Now, you'd probably be better off using libc's `_start`, because your current implementation would still segfault: you need to stop your program with the `exit` syscall, not with `ret`.

Michael's comment tells you how to use gcc to compile from assembly code (so you have libc's `_start`). If you still want to do it yourself your program needs to look like this:

```
BITS 32
GLOBAL _start
SECTION .text
_start:
    mov ebx, 42
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

You put `exit`'s syscall number in eax, the return code in ebx, and trigger the 0x80 interrupt.

Comment: Thanks, this solution stops the linker from complaining. However, on runtime, there is still a "Segmentation" fault error, followed by an incorrect return value of 139 instead of 42.

Comment: Sorry, I have the bad habit to post my answer first and edit it along when I try it to add further information. It should be complete now.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information and explaining `int 0x80` and the ebx return to me. I'm going to play around with it a bit more, I found a similar solution to someone else's problem, but was concerned that moving around extra values would increase the size of my program.